# filter the data in the matrix visual through a slicer and if the data is null in the visual then replace the null with 0 or "-"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to replace blanks with zero in a matrix visual. The Table has Employee Name, Courses, and Status of the Course. I have used Columns as Course, Status of the Course in Rows and Values as Status(Count). I have used a Slicer suppose Employee Name and the Values get filtered in the matrix visual. The specific employee would have taken 9 out of 10 courses. The 10th course Column Value should be shown as 0 or "-" instead of null. The purpose of the visual is to show the count of the status of the courses.
Somebody, Please help me out if there is a solution for such a scenario.
I would appreciate any assistance as I’ve been thinking about this for hours and have hit a wall. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write a measure

```
Measure = COUNT(Table[Status of course])+0
```

and place it in Values